# Drawing series of lines from hub in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, route, points-to-line

I'm trying to create a route map and was wondering how best to do this. I have a series of 'routes' emanating from hubs to single destinations and wish to link them creating a spoke-like effect like an airline route map.

Is there a way in QGIS 3 to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **Join by lines (hub lines)** tool for this.

> This algorithm creates hub and spoke diagrams by connecting lines from points on the Spoke layer to matching points in the Hub layer.